# Angular 2/4 background color multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to set up background color based on multiple conditions. I have currently

```
<td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': mod.tyle=='main' ? 'red' : 'black'}">{{mod.tyle}}</td>
```

I want to change so mod.tyle=high I want red  or if mod.tytle=low want yellow else none or white background. How can I add multiple conditions?

Comment: That's going to become an unreadable mess quickly. Extract the logic into an accessor on the component class instead, then you can just have e.g. `{'background-color': backgroundColor}` in the template.

Comment: you can use object instead of condition and you get `bgcolor` from that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component.ts

```
getColor(mycolor: number): string {
    switch (mycolor) {
      case 1: return '#EE6E73';
      case 2: return '#44C0FF';
      case 4: return '#D99415';
      case 5: return 'green'
    }
  }
```

Component.html

```
 <table *ngFor="let mod of tyles">
        <td [style.background-color]="getColor(mod.tyle)"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a property in your components class like this:

```
export class YourComponent {    
  public get backgroundColor() {
    switch(mod.tyle) {
      case 'high': return 'red';
      case 'low': return 'yellow';
      default: return 'white';
    }
  }
}
```

Use this property in your template:

```
<td [ngStyle]="{'background-color': backgroundColor}">{{mod.tyle}}</td>
```

Comment: when i use your solution for switch(mode.style) it says "Cannot find name 'mod' ...in code it is *ngFor="let mod of allmods"

Comment: I provided the solution according to your question. You did not mention about `*ngFor` in your question, how would I know about that ?